# Find substring in string from the end

Tags: c++

I need to find position of string in substring. Scan has to begin from the end. For example:

```
findch(L"asdhuifdsahdfasasd", L"asd");
```

return 16 instead of 1

Here is my function:

```
int findchr(LPCWSTR T, LPCWSTR P)
{
    int n = lstrlenW(T);
    int m = lstrlenW(P);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n - m; ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < m && T[i + j] == P[j]) {
            ++j;
        }
        if (j == m) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why does your loop start at `0` if you should start at the end?

Comment: this implementation from CRT source. I haven't changed it yet

Comment: What is your question then?  How to change this code to do what you want?

Comment: what did you try? Copying some code from somewhere is already something, but you can do more

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`std::string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) which does exactly what you want:

> Finds the last substring equal to the given character sequence.

Then you can have something like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string::size_type reverse_find(std::string const& str, std::string const& substr) {
    return str.rfind(substr);
}

int main() {
    auto first = reverse_find("asdhuifdsahdfasasd", "asd");
    if (std::string::npos != first) {
        std::cout << first << std::endl;  // 15
    }

    auto second = reverse_find("asdhuifdsahdfasasd", "z");
    if (std::string::npos != second) {
        std::cout << second << std::endl; // won't be outputted
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astd::string::size_type+reverse_find(std::string+const%26+str,+std::string+const%26+substr)+%7B%0A++++return+str.rfind(substr)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+first+%3D+reverse_find(%22asdhuifdsahdfasasd%22,+%22asd%22)%3B%0A++++if+(std::string::npos+!!%3D+first)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+first+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++auto+second+%3D+reverse_find(%22asdhuifdsahdfasasd%22,+%22z%22)%3B%0A++++if+(std::string::npos+!!%3D+second)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+second+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.637075718015666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.1',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.362924281984334,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Above `reverse_find` function returns 15 because indices start at 0.

Comment: i can't use <string>

Comment: @kor: Your question is tagged [tag:c++]. `std::string` is part of the C++ Standard Library. If you cannot use `<string>`, you have asked the wrong question.

Answer (score -3):

```
int findchr(LPCWSTR str, LPCWSTR substr)
{
    int n = lstrlenW(str);
    int m = lstrlenW(substr);

    for (int i = n; i >= m - n; --i) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < m && str[i + j] == substr[j]) {
            ++j;
        }
        if (j == m) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain your answer. I am not sure this could be a good solution to help future readers without a little more info.